# JAVA - font path instead font name in docx

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to generate .docx document. I added external fonts to my project. For example:

```
String playfairDisplayRegular = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf").getFile();
```

I used playfairDisplayRegular in paragraph. When I mark text in the document in the field with the name of the font is path for example:

```
/C:/Users/..../Documents...
```

instead of the **font name** (the font is working). Any ideas ?

Greetings, Artur

Answer (score 1):

`URL.getFile()` just returns the file name part (+ optional query part `?...`) of the URL.

For resources (files possibly inside a jar, residing on the class path) one should rather not use File, but use an InputStream, whenever possible.

With java.awt.Font:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
                            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf"));
```

In the docx you can now use `font.getFamily()` (for `XSLFTextRun.setFontFamily`) and such.

### Embedding fonts in the docx:

Meanwhile apache poi might be able to embed fonts (license issue for you!), but doing it yourself should be simple: .docx is a zip format, fonts are in a `/fonts/` subdirectory. You can test it in a small docx written in MSWord. Writing the file can be done by a zip file system: `"jar:file:/C:/... .docx"`, and `Files.copy`.

Comment: Thanks for response. My answer is down below

Answer (score 0):

Using **java.awt.Font** will be problematic for me, bacause my syntax looks like this:

```
printParagraph(createParagraphWithAlignment(document, ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT),
                "something",
                new Font(playfairDisplayRegular, 12, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE));
```

And methods used:

```
protected XWPFRun printParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String text, Font font) {
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText(text);
    run.setFontSize(font.getSize());
    run.setBold(font.getBold());
    run.setItalic(font.getItalic());
    run.setFontFamily(font.getName());
    return run;
}

protected XWPFParagraph createParagraphWithAlignment(IBody ibody, ParagraphAlignment alignment) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = castParagraph(ibody);
    paragraph.setAlignment(alignment);
    return paragraph;
}
```